# Linux display command works in terminal, but not in systemd service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, go, systemd

I made a web app to turn off my computer's screens, there are a few different technologies but it's fairly simple:

I have a html/js frontend that detects a button click (Screens On / Screens Off) which sends the option to the PHP backend via ajax

The php then connects over a tcp port, sending the option to a program written in golang

Then my golang program executes the command to turn off/on the screens.
The command it runs is ("xset -display :0 dpms force off")

The problem I'm having is that the command only works when im running the golang program in the terminal, but when i set it up as a service the command wont work.

This is the golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "net"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Launching server")

    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":7777")
    fmt.Println("Listening...\n")

    for {
        // accept connection on port
        conn, _ := ln.Accept()
        fmt.Println("New connection")

        // listen for message ending in \n
        message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        rec := string(message)

        // remove trailing \n
        rec = rec[:len(rec)-1]

        fmt.Println("Message Received: ", "\""+rec+"\"")

        returnMessage := "fail"

        if (rec == "screensOff") {
            fmt.Println("Turning off screens...")

            //execute screens off command
            cmd := exec.Command("xset", "-display", ":0", "dpms", "force", "off")
            stdout, err := cmd.Output()

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            } else {
                fmt.Println(string(stdout))
                returnMessage = "done"
            }
        } else if (rec == "screensOn") {
            fmt.Println("Turning on screens...");

            //execute screens on command
            cmd := exec.Command("xset", "-display", ":0", "dpms", "force", "on")

            stdout, err := cmd.Output()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            } else {
                fmt.Println(string(stdout))
                returnMessage = "done"
            }
            returnMessage = "done"
        } 

        conn.Write([]byte(returnMessage + "\n"))

        conn.Close()
        fmt.Println("Connection closed\n")
    }
}
```

And relevant PHP code:

```
<?php
function sendServiceMessage($message) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 7777;
    $timeout = 30;

    // connect to service
    $socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!is_resource($socket)) {
        exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr);
    }
    else {
        // send message
        fputs($socket, $message."\n");

        // receive return message
        $recieved = "";
        while (!feof($socket)) {
            $recieved .= fgets ($socket, 1024);
        }
    }

    // close connection
    fclose($socket);
    if ($recieved == "done") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

sendServiceMessage("screensOff");
```

I used systemd to set up the service, so after building the program and placing it in /usr/bin/

```
...$ go build screenControl.go
...$ sudo cp screenControl /usr/bin/screenControl
```

I can run the screenControl program in the terminal, and select "screens off" in the web app and it all works as expected:

```
...$ screenControl
Launching server
Listening...

New Connection
Message Received:  "screensOff"
Turning off screens...

Connection closed
```

I then created a systemd unit file (/etc/systemd/system/screenControl.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Screen control service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screenControl
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I started the service and checked it:

```
...$ systemctl start screenControl
...$ systemctl status screenControl
● screenControl.service - Screen control service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/screenControl.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-12-13 22:31:54 GMT; 6s ago
 Main PID: 19871 (screenControl)
   CGroup: /system.slice/screenControl.service
           └─19871 /usr/bin/screenControl

Dec 13 22:31:54 User systemd[1]: Started Screen control service.
Dec 13 22:31:54 User screenControl[19871]: Launching server
Dec 13 22:31:54 User screenControl[19871]: Listening...
```

So it's running, but then when I select screens off in the web app now, nothing happens... I checked the service status again and it is receiving the message to turn the screens off but the command is exiting with an error:

```
...
Dec 13 22:31:54 User screenControlTest[19871]: Launching server
Dec 13 22:31:54 User screenControlTest[19871]: Listening...
Dec 13 22:32:25 User screenControlTest[19871]: New connection
Dec 13 22:32:25 User screenControlTest[19871]: Message Received:  "screensOff"
Dec 13 22:32:25 User screenControlTest[19871]: Turning off screens...
Dec 13 22:32:25 User screenControlTest[19871]: exit status 1
Dec 13 22:32:25 User screenControlTest[19871]: Connection closed
```

What's the problem here and how can I get that command to work as a service? Once this is working I want to have the service start automatically when the machine turns on, although with systemd I think that's as simple as:

```
...$ systemctl enable screenControl
```

Any help would be great, thank you :)

***Edit***

After having the golang program show me the stderr of the xset command, I now also have the error message:

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

Comment: xwindows doesn't let users other than the current session owner to send it commands.  try "xhost +" from a shell (as you) before invoking your service.  it could be that root is getting blocked from turning off the screen.  but it works when you run commands from the shell since you own the session

Comment: I stopped the service, tried "xhost +" which said "access control disabled, clients can connect from any host" then started the service again but it's still getting "exit status 1" from the xset command :/

Comment: do you have the actual error message generated to go with the exit code 1?

Comment: I played around with go and got it to show me the stderr output too: (exit status 1: xset:  unable to open display "") I'm wondering if it's like you said, and that root is getting blocked, although I can run the golang program from a root terminal and it works.. but is that working because I started the root session (via "sudo -i") from the desktop users session? This is getting deeper than i expected it to, interesting stuff :)

Comment: when it says display "", that means it doesn't know which display.  When you execute a command line app from go, you can pass the environment, try doing that with DISPLAY=":0"

Comment: Awesome that worked! I set the display env using: 
cmd.Env = []string{"DISPLAY=:0"};
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per David Budworth's comment, the fix was exceedingly simple; as the service was running under root, it didn't have the DISPLAY environment variable set.

In go you can set the environment variables when using exec like so:

```
//execute screens off command
cmd := exec.Command("xset", "-display", ":0", "dpms", "force", "off")
cmd.Env = []string{"DISPLAY=:0"} // set the display before executing
stdout, stderr := cmd.CombinedOutput() //execute and return all output
```

And from James Henstridge answer I found I also needed to run `xhost +SI:localuser:root` to allow the root user access to the X server.

You can do this for users after they've logged in by adding this line to the top of the `/etc/profile` file

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**OR**

You can get it to work even when no user is logged in (when the login screen is showing)

First I created the directory `/opt/scripts`
then created the file `/opt/scripts/xhost.sh`
and gave it executable permissions with `chmod +x /opt/scripts/xhost.sh`

In this file is just the one line:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (I had to create it, but edit it if it's there) and add the line
`display-setup-script=/opt/scripts/xhost.sh`

So my `lightdm.conf` file looks like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
display-setup-script=/opt/scripts/xhost.sh
```

This tells LightDM (the display manager running in Ubuntu) to run the script `/opt/scripts/xhost.sh` after the X server is started but before anything else, therefore root is given the xhost authorization straightaway!

***note:***

display-setup-script is run after the X server starts but before the user session / greeter is run. Set this if you need to configure anything special in the X server. It is run as root. If this command returns an error code the X server is stopped.
*Source: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM_)*

Answer (score 1):

The `xset` command is just a client for the X server.  It determines which X server to talk to by checking the `DISPLAY` environment variable, which won't be set when you run your command as a system service.

And even if you ensured `DISPLAY` was set when running your daemon, it would likely be run as a different user account and denied access to the display by default.

A better option would be to run the your daemon as part of the user session.  This will solve the authentication issues (it will be running as you), and the ability to locate the display (the environment variable should be visible).  The daemon won't be running when you aren't logged in, but that probably doesn't matter for this particular use case.

You've tagged your question with "Ubuntu", where the session is still managed by [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).  You can create new user session jobs by creating a file in `~/.config/upstart`.  The details of the file format can be found in the [`init(5)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/init.5.html).

Comment: I thought Upstart was replaced with systemd in 15.04? (I'm on 15.10) But, indeed it wont work unless I run "xhost +" from the user session... Is it possible to authorize the root user to have access to display too? so no matter who is logged in, it will still work. Would there be any issues in doing that?

Comment: I notice I can run `xhost +SI:localuser:root` to get it to authorize the root user, so I put that at the bottom of the /etc/bash.bashrc file to run for all users, hopefully there's nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: Now its only working after logging into the desktop (which is fine, it would be nice if it worked while on the login screen, but meh) and then after having to open a terminal window... :s but it still works after closing the terminal... I don't even know what to google to fix that one :s So close to working!

Comment: Solved by putting the `xhost +SI:localuser:root` at the top of the `/etc/profile` file instead of the bash.bashrc file. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Prior to 15.04, you would have had two copies of Upstart running: the system one as pid 1, and a second one running as your user account to manage your desktop login session.  The system instance has indeed been replaced with systemd, but the user session one remains.  It will probably also be replaced with systemd at some point, but that hasn't happened yet.